# nodegit: cloning private repository using GitHub API token is not working

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, nodegit

I want to clone a private repository using nodegit, a npm package. I followed [a guides for cloning private repository](http://www.nodegit.org/guides/cloning/gh-two-factor/) and set the clone options as fllows,

```
cloneOptions:
  remoteCallbacks:
    certificateCheck: ()-> return 1
    credentials: ()->
      return NodeGit.Cred.userpassPlaintextNew(GITHUB_TOKEN, "x-oauth-basic")
```

but I got an error saying,`"authentication required but no callback set"`. So I checked some of the related source code of `nodegit` and set `cloneOptions` as follows,

```
cloneOptions =
  fetchOpts:
    callbacks:
      certificateCheck: ()-> return 1 # For OS X issue with GitHub certificate
      credentials: ()->
        cred = NodeGit.Cred.userpassPlaintextNew(GITHUB_TOKEN, "x-auth-basic")
        return cred
```

The behavior of this code is somewhat strange because it seems to clone the repository but `cloneOpts.fetchOpts.callbacks.credential()` is called repeatedly and the program doesn't stop running.

If I instead use username and password as arguments for `git.Cred.userpassPlaintextNew`, `credentials()` is called only once (which is the expected behavior) and the repository is cloned.

Can anyone give me some hints on what is wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 0):

When talking to a remote hosting service, bad credentials will cause nodegit to reattempt your request. Depending on if you're on Windows or Mac that request will retry indefinitely or it will retry 5 times.

So I would guess that your OAuth credentials are incorrect and nodegit is retrying the request continuously.